# Is this an aggregation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml, aggregation

I have the following code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Engine engine = new Engine("This Engine!");
    Car b = new Car(engine);

    b = null;
}
```

Is this an aggregation? I always think that an aggregation is when something can still "live" even if the other class is "destroyed"... so for example Car and Engine. if I delete the Car instance, the Engine can still live.

Is this correct?

Comment: it seems you got it all wrong cuz aggregation is about relationship or may be you try to convey that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would say that your code would look better when you do

```
Car b = new Car();
b.setEngine(engine);
```

would look better.

Then regarding your aggregation thinking, yes, you are correct. "Somehow". But this if you really split your "objects" fine grained. I mean, will you have a Car if it does not got an engine? :)

I would actually see the car as it is, **I would think more an aggregation for a Car and a Driver. If Car is damaged still you have a Driver. And if a Driver dies, still you have a Car.**

From `uml` about aggregation:

Aggregation is a variant of the "has a" association relationship; aggregation is more specific than association. It is an association that represents a part-whole or part-of relationship. As a type of association, an aggregation can be named and have the same adornments that an association can. However, an aggregation may not involve more than two classes; it must be a binary association.

Aggregation can occur when a class is a collection or container of other classes, but the contained classes do not have a strong lifecycle dependency on the container. The contents of the container are not automatically destroyed when the container is.

> composition/aggregation

Another relation which confuses with aggregation is the composition. When aggregation describes the "has" relation the composition do the "contains/part of" relation. As I said, normally, the engine is part of for you car object right (composition). The Car object has a Driver (aggregation).

Comment: Amazingly explained, thank you! May I ask you to also explain where the hollow diamond shape always belongs to? I kinda do not always understand it.. btw: I will accept your answer but I have to wait some more mins :D

Comment: you are welcome, the hollow diamond shape is e.g. Car <>----> Driver if this what you ask ? the diamond is close to the car shape.

Comment: I don't quite understand on which side I have to put the hollow (or filled) diamond shape.

Comment: The filled diamond is for composition, see my answer. The hollow for aggregation.

Comment: I am probably too stupid to express myself. I have problems when it comes to deciding on which side the diamond has to be.. if I have to put it near class X or class Y.

Comment: No problem, it is not so easy, but after some practice you will understand it. The diamond should be closer to the Car. A Car (filled diamond) consists of 1 part which is Engine. A Car (filled diamond) consists of 4 parts which are Tiers. A Car (hollow diamond) has one Driver.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your help. I feel now very secure for my exam tomorrow! :)

Answer (score 1):

***something can still "live" even if the other class is "destroyed".***

Yes, Aggregation is where B exists independently from A, e.g an Employee still exists without his Manager.

Compostion is stronger where object A "owns" B. B has no purpose except in relation to A.