# Avoiding diamond shapes in Java when using composition and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, composition

I've been building a system that has five classes, with another class containing the main method to initialize, show and modify various different objects from the aforementioned five classes. I understand how to use inheritance to adopt fields in both the therapist and patient classes from the person (e.g. *name, address phonenumber* fields) parent-class, and how to use composition (at-least theoretically) to build objects of consultation and bill from the patient class.

However, I'm confused on how I should go about storing a field called *therapist name* in the Therapist class and showing that when I call an object of patient. I've included a class diagram on how I think it should be like, but apparently this forms a diamond which is a big no-no in java. Would something like what's in my class diagram even work?

Could anyone show an example of how I store the *therapist name* in the Therapist class and then *move* that data member over to patient when I create its objects?

Here's a diagram:

[image: link]

Comment: Who told you that this arrangement was a "no no"?

Comment: That's...not actually a diamond.  A diamond would be if you wanted to make a subclass of both Patient and Therapist simultaneously.  You're fine.

Comment: Have you considered that a single patient may use multiple therapists?

Comment: @Bohemian This sounds like an assignment, and I wouldn't complicate things to N if only 1 is specified.

Comment: @Bohemian - I read your comment before I read the question. I though you were making a sarcastic comment on the insanity of multiple inheritance :)

Comment: Ahh okay, it kinda looks like an upside down diamonds so I was concered  I may run into issues. I feel like an idiot now. :)

Comment: You confuse composition and aggregation, see my answer with uml model and my thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220051/is-this-an-aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diamond problem doesn't really exist for Java, because Java only support multiple inheritance of signature, not of implementation (though I'm not sure how that works with Java 8 interface default methods -- I haven't messed with them that thoroughly yet). The diamond problem in multi-inheritance-of-implementation languages refers to the problem of one class inheriting the same grandparent class through two different parent classes. In C++, for instance, you'll either get the grandchild having two distinct grandparent instances (one per parent class), so you can get two different results from casting your object to a grandparent, depending on which parent the cast comes from; or you'll have a single grandparent instance, shared by both parents -- who might update the grandparent using different semantics.

In this case, if you want to add a `therapistName` field to `Patient`, just add a field called `therapistName` and initialize it either through a constructor param or a setter. There's no problem here.

Bottom line: the diamond pattern is only a no-no for multiple inheritance of implementation, which Java doesn't support (again, possibly excluding interface default methods). A diamond caused by composition isn't an antipattern, nor is it likely to cause you pain, other than perhaps making initialization and/or disposal logic more cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! That really cleared my question up for me and has given me the confidence to try it out in practice. With that said, I'm not quite sure where I got the idea that diamonds caused by composition would result in errors - it was probably a result of my own misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned about the diamond you worried, I wanted to make some marks about your diagram.

Check the arrows below.

And about the composition you have it wrong, the relation between the patient and therapist is an aggregation relation. A composition relation you can see it more as "part of". I wrote a simple thread about it too here , read: [Is this an aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220051/is-this-an-aggregation)

[image]