# Should I use aggregation if accessing object via another object?

Tags: java, uml

If I access an object via another object, do I still need to represent this as aggregation (or composition) in UML diagrams? For example, if a Garage has a Car, and a Car has an Engine, If Garage accesses Engine using Car.Engine, does Garage need to include Engine and Car, or only Car ? I don't want needless associations cluttering the diagrams, so hopefully Garage can just include Car. Thanks.

Comment: That's great. Thank you.

Comment: In a word: no. You do not need to include `Engine` in your `Garage`. All members of a class should only reside within that class's diagram.

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640885/uml-aggregation-vs-association and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220051/is-this-an-aggregation?r=SearchResults&s=6|56.8506

Answer (score 1):

No, Garage would not need any association to Engine, because it is not directly associated with it.

If you really want to emphasize that Garage uses Engine, you can draw a general association ("-->") between them, but aggregation or composition would be wrong here.

Comment: Instead of a general association, I think a dependency (dashed arrow), perhaps stereotyped as ≪use≫, would be more appropriate. But you are right, the diagram can do without it.